# how to initialize javascript plugin?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use this javascript plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/maxlength-contenteditable#commonjs 
The issue is that I do not understand how to initialize it.

My path to plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/maxlength-contenteditable/dist/maxlength-contenteditable.js"></script>
```

Using the plugin on my html

```
<div class="myDiv" contenteditable="true" data-max-length="10"></div>
```

In the documents it says to initialize by one of three ways using:

```
var maxlengthContentEditableLib = require('maxlength-contenteditable');
```

Can someone explain how I would use the initialization and where?

Comment: Open your browser console - what errors do you see?

Comment: @WillardSolutions  ReferenceError: require is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE LOCALLY:**

If you want to do it locally do it like this:
Install it:

```
$ npm install maxlength-contenteditable --save
```

Then paste this code in your file for test purposes:

```
<style>
  h2 {
    color: lightslategray;
  }
  span {
      color: red;
  }

  .content-editable-element {
    border: 1px solid lightslategray;
    width: 300px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <h2>maxlength contenteditable demo</h2>
  <span>the max length is set to 10!!!!</span>
  <div class="content-editable-element" contenteditable="true" data-max-length="10"></div>
  <script src="node_modules/maxlength-contenteditable/dist/maxlength-contenteditable.js"></script>
  <script>maxlengthContentEditableModule.maxlengthContentEditable();</script>
</body>
```

Instead of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/maxlength-contenteditable/dist/maxlength-contenteditable.js"></script>
```

Why don't you simply do:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/maxlength-contenteditable@1.0.1/dist/maxlength-contenteditable.js"></script>
```

Your problem is in your path, probably. Try to use the CDN version instead.

If you use the CDN Version, then in the JS you do:

```
<script>
    maxlengthContentEditableModule.maxlengthContentEditable(); // to initialize
</script>
```

Working here:

```js
maxlengthContentEditableModule.maxlengthContentEditable();
```

```css
  .content-editable-element {
    border: 1px solid lightslategray;
    width: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/maxlength-contenteditable@1.0.1/dist/maxlength-contenteditable.js"></script>

<div class="content-editable-element" contenteditable="true" data-max-length="10"></div>
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Working now, check it out.

Comment: The path is correct, I get an 200 OK status for the script. Using the  CDN version works, but I would like see if I can get it working locally.